# defining json schema which considers case sensitive in validating incoming request

Tags: xml, json, validation, rest, xslt

i have a JSON request which validate over JSON schema definition and an XSLT is used to convert request to some format.

The problem is, if the incoming request doesn't  follow the case sensitive according to scheme the xslt transformation failed as the field is extracted using the name(case-sensitive).

Surprising is that the schema validation doen't fails or throw bad request if the request doesn't follow case sensitive.

eg :

valid request need to be as below according to schema:
{
"Name":"tt",
"Age":23
}

sample request follow the schema but it not follow case sensitive:
{
"name":"tt",
"Age":23
}

name attribute should be "Name".

The question is:
How can we validate the request with considering case-sensitive attribute fields  ?
(or)
How can we define the schema which considers case sensitive ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a validation which is case sensitive, such as the following:

```
var foo = ["\u0022Name\u0022:","\u0022Age\u0022:"];
var bar = {"name":"tt","Age":23};
var baz = RegExp(foo[0]).test(JSON.stringify(bar)) //false
var bop = RegExp(foo[1]).test(JSON.stringify(bar)) //true
```

**References**

- [Test Method(Regular Expression)(JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/a55e5s6b(v=vs.94).aspx)